# How to find the pointer node of a relationship using full text search on the edge node in neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-theory

This question is related to Neo4j databases. Suppose I have a relationship (employee)-[WORKS-IN]->(company).. Imagine an employee works in multiple companies. I should be able to find the companies that a specific employee is working using full text search in neo4j. I'll be searching from the users name and I should be able to return company nodes..how to do that??

Full text search must be used.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to search for a Person by name with full text and then retrieve the companies he worked for.

Compare this easily with the default Movies graph in Neo4j, you want to search for a Person by name with full text and then retrieve the movies the person acted in .

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('Person', 'kea*')
YIELD node
MATCH (node)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
RETURN node.name, movie.title
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorted it out. And one more thing. Suppose for a particular worker there can be various relationships except [WORKS-IN] , such as [PART TIME WORKER] , [FREELANCER], [PROJECT MANAGER] and so on. So for a particular user, If we want to find the place or company that he is working, freelancing, managing projects by searching the relationship type how could it be done using full text search.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example when I created this node:

```
CREATE (e:Employee {name: 'Nirmana Testing'})
```

Then create the full text index on Employee.name

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX employeeNameIdx FOR (e:Employee) ON EACH [e.name]
```

Then run a query using this full text index. Noted that the keyword 'nirmana' can be upper case or any case.

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("employeeNameIdx", "nirmana") YIELD node as employee
MATCH (employee)-[:WORKS-IN]->(company:Company)
RETURN employee, company
```

reference:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-full-text-search/

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorted it out. And one more thing. Suppose for a particular worker there can be various relationships except [WORKS-IN] , such as [PART TIME WORKER] , [FREELANCER], [PROJECT MANAGER] and so on. So for a particular user, If we want to find the place or company that he is working, freelancing, managing projects by searching the relationship type how could it be done using full text search.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. Sorted it out. And one more thing. Suppose for a particular worker there can be various relationships except [WORKS-IN] , such as [PART TIME WORKER] , [FREELANCER], [PROJECT MANAGER] and so on. So for a particular user, If we want to find the place or company that he is working, freelancing, managing projects by searching the relationship type how could it be done using full text search.